# Selenium python how I preform a click on toggle button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click in call loop toggle with Selenium with the WebDriver on Python.

the html code:

[image]

this is the button:

[image]

I have tried few options:

```
button_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("iPhoneCheckContainer")
button_element.click()
```

the filed message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kosti\PycharmProjects\test1\main.py", line 50, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='on_off_on']").click()
  File "C:\Users\kosti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\kosti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\kosti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\kosti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="checkbox" id="on_off_on" value="1" name="AllowReset" checked=""> is not clickable at point (171, 261). Other element would receive the click: <div class="iPhoneCheckHandle" style="width: 30px; left: 30px;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)
```

Comment: Please add html as code

Comment: It's just that he targeted the div not the input.

Comment: pkease add html as code not image

Comment: @ArundeepChohan some times div is also interactable example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content , but here it might be because of the issue you mentioned but unlesss we know how the html is rendered its hard to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

elem=WebDriverWait(driver,5000).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='on_off_on']")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",elem)

element.click()
```

Try using webdriver wait

Comment: to get xpath go to f12 then into the path right ciick on the element and copy the copy xpath

Answer (score 1):

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_id("on_off_on")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",elem)
```

Try targeting the input id instead.

Comment: Didn't worked


_____log: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="checkbox" id="on_off_on" value="1" name="AllowReset" checked=""> is not clickable at point (171, 261). Other element would receive the click: <div class="iPhoneCheckHandle" style="width: 30px; left: 30px;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)

Comment: Try this instead